# How to re-draw a line after rotating the model

Tags: aframe

I want to have a line that points to some specific points of a 3d Model with a 2DCanvas, but this line should continue pointing to the same point of the model even after moving/rotating it, so the line has to be redrawn, and the initial position re-calculated.

This is a codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWKQrO  where you can see my intention.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-html-shader@0.2.0/dist/aframe-html-shader.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-line-component/dist/aframe-line-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('drag-rotate-component',{
      schema : { speed : {default:1}},
      init : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
        this.x_cord = 0;
        this.y_cord = 0;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown',this.OnDocumentMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',this.OnDocumentMouseUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove',this.OnDocumentMouseMove.bind(this));
      },
      OnDocumentMouseDown : function(event){
        this.ifMouseDown = true;
        this.x_cord = event.clientX;
        this.y_cord = event.clientY;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseUp : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseMove : function(event)
      {
        if(this.ifMouseDown)
        {
          var temp_x = event.clientX-this.x_cord;
          var temp_y = event.clientY-this.y_cord;
          if(Math.abs(temp_y)<Math.abs(temp_x))
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateY(temp_x*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          else
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateX(temp_y*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;
        }
      }
    });
</script>



<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: true">
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="brainstem" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/brainstem/BrainStem.gltf"></a-asset-item>

  </a-assets>


  <a-entity gltf-model="#brainstem" position="0 0 -5" scale="3 3 3" drag-rotate-component >
    </a-entity>


     <a-entity  line geometry="primitive: plane" material="shader: html; target: #boxHTML" position="3 5 -5"></a-entity>


     <a-entity position="0 -0.5 2">
       <a-camera look-controls="enabled:false"></a-camera>
     </a-entity>



  <!--<a-obj-model  scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" src="#crate-obj" mtl="#crate-mtl"></a-obj-model>-->


 <a-entity line="start: 3 5 -5; end: 0.5 2 -5; color: #000000"></a-entity>
  <a-sky color="#FAFAFA"></a-sky>

<!-- HTML to render as a material. -->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden">
      <div id="boxHTML" style="background-image: url(bad.png); color: white; width: 240px; height: 250px; font-size: 64px; font-family: monospace; text-align: center">
        <p style="background: rgb(30, 30, 30); position: absolute; top: 25px; width: 250px">Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</a-scene>
```

How could i re-draw the line after rotating?

Thanks!

Answer : Done here : https://codepen.io/spaboy/pen/OOWvKP

Comment: Hi, I manage to do this. Added Codepen to the answer

Comment: Don't have time to provide a detailed answer. But know you can update the line with `.setAttribute('line', {start: newStart, end: newEnd})` and you'll need to do some math or use raycasters to determine what those new values are.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the line with `.setAttribute('line', {start: newStart, end: newEnd})`. Just change the `newEnd` to point to the new spot. You need to do some transform/math to determine what that new spot is after the model has rotated.

Perhaps I would add an `THREE.Object3D` to the object (`.setObject3D('point', yourObject3D)`). Then set the object 3d's position to the point that you want to point at. Then when the model rotates, it's an easy way to get the new point in world space using `el.object3D.updateMatrixWorld(); yourObject3D.getWorldPosition();`. Use that new world position as the new end point.